# conda: The pytorch and nvidia channels aren't playing nicely together

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, miniconda

If I set up a conda pytorch environment like this:

```
conda activate pytorch-cuda
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

That works; at least insofar as being able to import torch in python.  If, however, I add cuDNN:

```
conda install cudnn -c nvidia
```

Things are no longer warm and fuzzy:

```
(torch-cuda1) pgoetz@finglas ~$ python --version
Python 3.11.5
(torch-cuda1) pgoetz@finglas ~$ python
Python 3.11.5 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:54:46) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/lusr/opt/miniconda/envs/torch-cuda1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 229, in <module>
from torch._C import *  # noqa: F403
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: /lusr/opt/miniconda/envs/torch-cuda1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10_cuda.so: undefined symbol: cudaMemPoolSetAttribute, version libcudart.so.11.0
>>>
```

What's happening is the cuDNN conda package is installing and relinking an older version of **libcudart.so.11.0**.  Here is what is in **~/miniconda/envs/pytorch-cuda/lib**  before cuDNN is installed:

```
# ls -l libcudart*
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 695712 Sep 21  2022 libcudart.so.11.8.89
```

Here is what it looks like after the cudnn package is installed from the nvidia channel:

```
# ls -l libcudart*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Sep 25 13:12 libcudart.so -> libcudart.so.11.1.74
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Sep 25 13:12 libcudart.so.11.0 -> libcudart.so.11.1.74
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 554032 Oct 14  2020 libcudart.so.11.1.74
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 695712 Sep 21  2022 libcudart.so.11.8.89
```

It looks like something similar is happening with **libcusparse.so.11**, and possibly other libraries, I didn't bother trying to track them all down.

Hmm, so maybe try using only the pytorch channel?  No matter how far I pare it down, this somehow results in unresolvable dependency problems and nothing gets installed:

```
conda install pytorch  pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch
```

So it appears that using different channels can result in software incompatibilities, but in some cases the use of multiple channels is unavoidable, so then the question becomes which channel(s) to use for what task environments? The installation matrix on the pytorch.org website specifically recommends this:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

However many of my users also want cuDNN -- how can I get cuDNN installed in a pytorch environment in such a way that it doesn't break pytorch?

Beyond this, whom can should I bring these issues up with? The maintainers of the pytorch and nividia channels? Should one only be using conda-forge instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like `pytorch-cuda=11.8` is not corretly listing its `libcudart` dependency if it is indeed incompatible with `libcudart.so.11.1.74`. Have you raised this issue on the pytorch github?

Comment: Hmm. The mess here seems to be `cudnn` on the **nvidia** channel only goes to 8.0.4 (that's old). While the PyTorch channel seems to have `cudnn` specifications in their build strings for `pytorch`, there is no actual info in the metadata to constrain it. I'm not sure who is to blame, and the PyTorch channel's change from building against **defaults** channel to **nvidia** muddies how to give a clear downgrade recommendation. I.e., using **nvidia** channel seems to entail CUDA 11.1 for cuDNN support, but I believe PyTorch was building against **defaults** then.